# Data table row slide up

Tags: jquery, datatables, slidetoggle

Has any one had issues with a data table row sliding up.  I am able to get the row to slide down but each time I click my button to close the row it just creates additional rows.

I've tried using the toggle method but that just still added an additional row and i've tried the slide up by just going after the tblIndsutry td.control and it still just adds and additional row.  i seems to always be -1

```
    //CLICK EVENT
$('#tblIndustry td.control').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

    if (i === -1) {
        industryDrillDown(tbls.industry, nTr);
    } //end if

    //$(nTr).find('.control i').fadeOut();
}); //ends click event
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use Toggle jquery? I think , it can help you

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/